# Mac OS X Terminal command stuck after pressing up arrow

Tags: macos, terminal

In my mac terminal, after pressing up a couple of times to see my previous commands, a command gets stuck in the terminal. It goes something like this,

Normal:

```
[ 10:23:34 ] > MY_COMMAND
```

After a couple of times pressing up

```
[ 10:23:34 ] > git commit -mMY_COMMAND
[ 10:23:35 ] > git commit -mMY_COMMAND
[ 10:23:36 ] > git commit -mMY_COMMAND
```

The `git commit -m` is just stuck there until I type 'clear' in the terminal. How do I fix this?

Comment: Which shell are you using?  Does the shell prompt include any instructions for the terminal?  Does this only happen for extremely long commands (that may wrap off the end), or all of them?

Comment: Mac OS X terminal using Bash. An no this happens with every command long or short.

Comment: This is my .bash_profile


export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/offirgolan/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
export TERM="xterm-color"
alias ls="ls -G"
export PS1="\e[1;30m\][\e[\e[1;30m\]\e[1;33m\] \u@\H \[\e[1;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\] \e[1;30m\]]\n[\[ \e[1;31m\]\T\[\e[0m\]\e[1;30m\] ] > \e[37m\]"

# set default file/directory creation protection for better security
umask 077

#our default text editor, could be emacs to
export EDITOR=emacs

#better pager than more
export PAGER=less

#Standard backspace
stty erase  intr

Comment: The `PS1` specification you posted seems very over-encoded...it doesn't seem capable of producing the prompt that you show above.  For instance you seem to add a bunch of end-brackets (`]`) that are not needed and are insignificant to the terminal.  I simplified it to this string...please try: `PS1="\e[1;30m\e[1;30m\e[1;33m \u@\H \e[1;32m\w\e[0m \e[1;30m\n[ \e[1;31m\T\e[0m\e[1;30m ] > \e[37m "`.  I think this is a likely cause because a problem in your prompt has a chance to screw things up *every* time a new prompt is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is an incorrectly formatted `PS1` prompt string. When you put non-printing control characters in the prompt you must surround them with `\[ … \]` to tell Bash to not count them when calculating the width of the prompt.

If the width calculation is incorrect, the command-line display can get messed up in several ways, including the way you've described.

In a comment you wrote:

> This is my .bash_profile export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/offirgolan/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools export TERM="xterm-color" alias ls="ls -G" export PS1="\e[1;30m][\e[\e[1;30m]\e[1;33m] \u@\H [\e[1;32m]\w[\e[0m] \e[1;30m]]\n[[ \e[1;31m]\T[\e[0m]\e[1;30m] ] > \e[37m]"

It looks like you may have intended to include bracketing, because of all the extra brackets without a leading backslash, but they are inconsistent and your string even contains incomplete escape sequences like `\e[\e[`. It's difficult to tell which brackets, if any, you intended to display in the prompt, and what color you want them, but your `PS1` should be something more like

```
PS1='\[\e[1;30m\][\[\e[1;30m\e[1;33m\] \u@\H [\[\e[1;32m\] \w\[\e[0m \e[1;30m\]]\n[ \[\e[1;31m\]\T\[\e[0m\e[1;30m\] ] > \[\e[37m\]'
```

**Pro-Tip:** Don't hard-code terminal commands in your prompt—they aren't portable and won't work with all terminals. Instead, use `tput` to select the appropriate command sequences for the current terminal. For example

```
PS1="\[$(tput setaf 1)\]Red Text\[$(tput sgr0)\] \$ "
```

will display the prompt "Red Text $ " with “Red Text” in red. This also makes it much easier to see whether the `\[ \]` brackets are correct, because you don't have literal escape characters littering the string, and the mnemonic `tput` codes make it easier to figure out what commands are being sent.